# PHP - Print PDF files

Tags: php, printing

I need to print several PDF files direct to printer, it could be using windows installed printer or via socket...

I've tested this solution http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html

And with this code PHP code (only for test) works

```
<?php

//$printerName = "VirtualPDF";
$printerName = "HP9D1C93 (HP Deskjet 3540 series)";
//$printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
$file = "\"C:\wamp64\www\dev\printer\JT0601502090104.pdf\"";

//copy /b \path\to\filename.pdf > \\Printer_Machine\Printer_Queue
// $cmd = "print /d:" . $printerName . " " . $file;

//PDFtoPrinter filename.pdf "Name of Printer"
$cmd = "PDFtoPrinter.exe " . $file . " \"" . $printerName . "\"";
echo $cmd;
echo utf8_encode(shell_exec($cmd));

?>
```

But in my case, some of PDF files can be created in SolidWorks and page size is A3. But, the printer that will be used is an A4 printer and it print out of scale. 
Has anyway to send the PDF file to printer and for to be "resized" (?) to A4 page size?

And if it only can be achieved with sockets, any ideas in how to do that?

Comment: Interesting how you use PHP to run a CMD command. Why not just use a batch file and skip PHP completely?

Comment: @Andreas In my case, isn't just print files... PHP was used to get some information from user, and lot of validations with our ERP...
I've just simplified things to ask only the this specifc problem...